# Email Subscriptions not filtering correctly

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have 2 subscriptions set up, one local and one remote. The rules that I have setup are not being followed though. My remote subscription is no longer filtering based on the tag c#, as I am getting emails with jobs that do not include a c# tag.

My local tag is firing very sporadically.

If I go to the page to manage my subscriptions, and click on view current jobs, I see jobs recently posted that I was not alerted about.

Comment: I don't believe the tag search has ever worked properly.  Tag search is the same as keyword search (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264680/improving-search-in-stack-overflow-careers)