# Careers email subscription ignoring location criteria

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have 2 subscriptions set up in Careers/Jobs, both for the term [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell), one for jobs within 50 miles of New York, NY, and one for remote jobs.

I just got an email, and it seems to be ignoring the distance/remote part of the filter and just giving me every job posting that lists the term (twice, once under the heading of remote jobs and once under the distance heading).

For example, it showed me a (non-remote) job in Chicago which is definitely not within 50 miles of New York. Jobs in other countries too. I have a whole list that don't match my criteria now (this used to be working).

The [closest other question I could find](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311893/email-subscriptions-not-filtering-correctly) seems to be about not showing jobs with the right tag, but showing the correct location so I don't think this is a duplicate, but maybe I missed another question somewhere.

Comment: Happening to me too, in the search. Showing jobs in the Netherlands and such. Maybe it's a bug right now.

Comment: @Shadaez hm I just tried a search and it seems to be returning the correct results. Maybe it was fixed quickly, but I probably won't receive another email for a day or so to know for sure whether I can say the same about the emails.

Comment: Ya this is a bug with search. I noticed it as well because of email alerts. Mine is set to "Japan" which hardly ever gets postings. If you search for it right now, you get 1000s in places like Canada and the US. There should only be 1 result.

Comment: Are all of the jobs that you're seeing listed as "offers relocation"?  I'm seeing the same thing (jobs in California when I live in Ontario).  This seems to be a fairly recent change, since I distinctly remember seeing jobs with the proper distance restriction not too long ago.

Comment: @cimmanon no, some of them are `offering relocation`, some are also `offering visa sponsorship`, but most offer neither. None of them are showing `work remotely` actually (I think there might just not be any of those available at the moment that match the tag).

Comment: Still happening :(

Comment: I've noticed the same sort of problem happening in my equivalent RSS feeds too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report, briantist. I've just deployed a fix that should handle this problem. Sorry for the bug and the annoying e-mail.

Comment: No problem, 2 emails in 48 hours isn't bad. Glad to help; thanks for the fix!

Comment: Does that fix include the visa sponsorship bug as well? I've noticed the emails also does not filter on that?