# Filters in Stack Overflow Jobs do not appear to be filtering

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Overall, I think that Careers 2.0 was much better than Stack Overflow jobs which is really buggy. What I really liked was your filters, specifically, where it said, "relocation offered", and "visa sponsorship". Those features felt like they were working but now they don't function properly. They show other jobs as well which don't have relocation offers or visa sponsorship.

I have tried these filters together as well as one by one separately and seem that it is overall buggy. So you guys need to do proper testing.
So here my question is that when can I check back and see it working and can have that same experience that I had with my favorite Careers 2.0?

Comment: Yup, and overall KDE4 was much worse than what came before, and so was GNOME3. At first. Maybe. I'm not using them, anyway. However, it does look like there are a lot of bugs opened against the new jobs feature, and that feature *may* suffer from early exposure to a very wide community. Only time will tell.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info

Comment: Are you saying that you're in software development & you don't know what beta testing is? Jobs is in beta, so expect bad/buggy things to happen.

Comment: After editing this a wee bit I can actually see a bug report buried underneath the vitriol.  Would you be okay with reposting this as, "It doesn't seem like the filters for relocation or visa sponsorship are working right now"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Careers email subscription ignoring location criteria](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312934/careers-email-subscription-ignoring-location-criteria)

Comment: It's not that bad considering its in beta. Almost every single bug I have posted has been addressed some way or another. And I'm quite certain the ones that haven't been addressed will be soon.  Give it time and be patient as the team has a lot of work ahead of them, the last thing they need to hear is someone stating an older process or piece of software was better.  Software is always changing so hop on board and move on and forget the complaining.  Use the bug and jobs tag to address your concerns.

Comment: sometime you want to report a bug but don't have proper time to convey exact thing so you want to atleast highlight it but seems like this was wrong thing to atleast on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There have been a *flurry* of bug reports on this feature over the last few days, and in all honesty, that's a good thing; testers can be sure that certain things *work*, but it's up to us to actually use it and see what's going on.

To my knowledge, there was also a limitation on how many eyes could actually get on Careers, since it was always invite only and there wasn't as many people kicking the tires as fervently as there are now.

As a fellow developer, if we see bugs, we should go ahead and report them.  I feel some level of sympathy when those sorts of things escape into production, but there's a lot of stuff that's wonky that they probably didn't catch, and that's okay - what matters now is that we report it and give them the chance to fix it.

Saying "it's buggy" is kind of like saying "it doesn't work"; it conveys that there *is* a problem, but not what the problem *is*.  Don't be too afraid to file a bug report or two if you see something amiss.

Comment: My purpose to post it here is improvement as i am active user for last few years when it was called career 2.0. And i want to tell that it was fine few days ago when it was career 2.0 but nowadays it have those errors that it dont filter results properly when i use relocation offered and visa sponsorship option. I didn't see this option on other sites.  So it was my favorite feature and now this is not working properly.

Comment: Also yes you got it right when saying buggy with these words, it means much problematic almost similar to don't work. And at-least in job boards, I think you should consider the search filters and one of the most important thing.

Comment: Seems like it is fixed now. and only you considered it as a bug reported, so i am marking it correct here. if this was going to be a bug reporting tool i would mark it resolved. But here i can only mark it correct.

Answer (score 5):

We definitely had a problem with job search over the last 48 hours that would've caused the problem you were seeing. I've pushed a fix and those filters should be working for you now. Sorry for the bug.

As for Careers 2.0 vs Jobs on Stack Overflow...Jobs on Stack Overflow is just a smart proxy to Careers 2.0. All the backend code is the same, so bugs that you see on one you should see on the other (excluding ones having to do with our proxy). We moved a little too fast on this search change and broke something, it was broken in both places.